# MySQL: Finding the most efficient use of INNER JOIN with subquery

Tags: mysql, join, in-subquery

I have a working query using INNER JOIN and a subquery but was wondering if there is a more effient way of writing it.

```
with prl
as
(
SELECT `number`, creator, notes
FROM ratings
INNER JOIN
    projects on ratings.project_id = projects.project_id
    WHERE ratings.rating = 5 AND projects.active = 1
)
SELECT prl.`number`, creator, notes
FROM prl
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT `number`
    HAVING COUNT(creator) > 1
)temp ON prl.`number` = temp.`number`
ORDER BY temp.`number`
```

projects table

```
project_id| number | creator | active |
|   1     |   3    |  bob    |    1   |
|   2     |   4    |  mary   |    1   |
|   3     |   5    |  asi    |    1   |
```

rating table

```
project_id|  notes | rating |
|   1     |  note1 |    5   |
|   1     |  note2 |    5   |
|   3     |  note3 |    5   |
|   1     |  note4 |    1   |
|   2     |  note5 |    5   |
|   3     |  note6 |    2   |
```

result

```
| number | creator |  notes |
|   3    |  bob    |  note1 |
|   3    |  bob    |  note2 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're using MySQL version that support window function. If so, then try this:

```
SELECT number, creator, notes
FROM
(SELECT p.number, p.creator, r.notes,
       COUNT(creator) OVER (PARTITION BY creator) AS cnt
 FROM project p 
  JOIN rating r ON p.project_id=r.project_id
WHERE r.rating=5
   AND p.active = 1) v
WHERE cnt=2;
```

As far as whether this is more efficient, I'm not really sure because it depends in your table indexes but for a small dataset, I assume this will do well.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3c8ea22c16b641bf274a099d8695f9f)

Comment: This is certainly more compact, but testing it with my local dataset of around 2500 for ratings and 500 for projects it takes twice as long to complete.  Any suggestions on making it more efficient?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the structure for both tables so please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` for both tables and post the result into your question.

Comment: I am also placing a limit on the query and this answer takes about the same time to complete, so I will mark it as the best answer.

Comment: If the current query return results in more than a second, here's a couple of things you can try to make it faster. 1. Create indexes - start with column(s) appear in `WHERE` (in the main query, of course). 2. In case `r.rating` and/or `p.active` datatype is `VARCHAR()`, both which appear in `WHERE`, then you may try adding quotes for the lookup values like `WHERE r.rating='5' AND p.active='1'`. Without the quotes, even if any of the column have index, it might not be effective due to the datatype and lookup value mismatch (`VARCHAR x INT`).